# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'btre.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to learn django framework and getting this error when trying to run the server. Can anybody please point me to the right direction. Things were working fine, before I ran the python manage.py collectstatic and then created the templates.

Seems like I am getting an error importing module error but I am not sure what to look into.

```
Django settings for btre project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewnoMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'btre.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'btre.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]
```

Error logs :

```
(venv) Rizwans-MBP:btre_project rizwanrenesa$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

November 22, 2018 - 08:02:36
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'btre.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x106f89158>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    return getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.middleware.csrf' has no attribute 'CsrfViewnoMiddleware'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 44, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/btre/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 34, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 24, in import_string
    ) from err
ImportError: Module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "CsrfViewnoMiddleware" attribute/class

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'btre.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
^Z
[7]+  Stopped                 python manage.py runserver
(venv) Rizwans-MBP:btre_project rizwanrenesa$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

November 22, 2018 - 08:02:52
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'btre.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10e0a6158>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    return getattr(module, class_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.middleware.csrf' has no attribute 'CsrfViewnoMiddleware'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 44, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/btre/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 34, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 24, in import_string
    ) from err
ImportError: Module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "CsrfViewnoMiddleware" attribute/class

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/rizwanrenesa/Desktop/btre_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'btre.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you've added "no" in the middle of one of the built-in middleware class names: "CsrfViewnoMiddleware" should be "CsrfViewMiddleware".

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have had a typo there.